# Products disappearing when adding any category on WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Has anyone experienced this before? This is my first time working with WooCommerce.

If I don't add products to a category they will show up in the main shop page as well as have a single product page, as soon as I add a category they will not show up on the main shop page, the category page, or the single product page.

I have not manipulated the wp_query in any way on the page.

I am integrating it into my custom theme which is really barebones, the only thing I have changed is the following in my functions.php file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'urbantac_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'urbantac_wrapper_end', 10);
function urbantac_wrapper_start() { echo '<div id="products-content" class="products wrap clearfix aligncenter content-container">'; }
function urbantac_wrapper_end() { echo '</div>'; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using another WooCommerce plugin:
http://www.woothemes.com/products/catalog-visibility-options/ to turn off the "store" functionality of WooCommerce and use it as a "catalog"

This adds two settings on the product category pages, and sets defaults to NOT show anyone the content (no idea why this is).  The settings are Role Visibility Rules and Location Visibility Rules.  It does not mention this anywhere in the documentation for the plugin!

So if you are using this plugin you can no longer create categories directly from a product page, you  must first create the category, set the visibility rules, and then create the product.